# How to transfert a domain to azure

Tags: azure, ovh

I have bought a domain from OVH and I want to transfert it to my azure subscription.

I Have unlocked the domain in OVH and got my Auth/Info code.

But when I try to buy the unprotected domain on azure, it doesn't appear in the select list.

The domain is a .net domain.

So, do you know how to transfert a, unprotected .net domain from ovh to azure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't transfer as such, the process is pointing the domain at your specific service. If you are pointing your domain at an [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/) then you need to make some DNS changes on your domain.

For Web Apps, the process is at follows:

1. In your browser, open the Azure Portal.
2. Click the Browse option on the left side of the page.
3. Click the **Web Apps** blade.
4. Click the name of your web app.
5. In the **Essentials** page, click **All settings**.
6. Click **Custom domains and SSL**.
7. In the Custom domains and SSL blade, click **Bring External Domains**. The IP address is located at the bottom of this part.

Then you can create an A record in DNS for your domain pointing to the IP you got from the above steps and a CNAME pointing to yoursite.azurewebsites.net.

For A records, you will need to create a awverify record in DNS, details on how to do this are in the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/#create-an-awverify-record-a-records-only).

Comment: Well I already tried that, but when I modify the cname in ovh, it automaticaly add my old domain name in the end of the cname. example: I have to point mydomain.net to mynewdomain.azurewebsite.net, and the cname becomes mynewdomain.azurewebsite.net.mydomain.net. I guess it's a protection from OVH but their app manager is just terrible. And I know it is possible to transfert a domain from a provider (ovh) to another (azure), I just don't now how.

Comment: You can't transfer your domain to Azure, you can point it at Azure but not transfer it. You would have to transfer it to someone like GoDaddy or NameCheap etc.

Comment: I figured out what happened, OVH has linked a server host to my domain, so I couldn't access my DNS zone nor the configuration of the domain. I asked OVH to unlink the domain and the host and now I can access my DNS and I can bring external domains for Azure, so you were right, it is just OVH who wasn't clear. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent glad I could help, I've seen this with 1&1 before to be honest, that they point domains to VMs so it's not really clear how to edit DNS.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer your domain from `XYZ` domain register, for example https://www.hover.com/, go to Azure Portal and use the `App Service Domain` service, which is currently in Preview state.